# .htaccess - rewrite multiple links (wildcard)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have big set of links - example:

```
tempfile-1.php 
tempfile-2.php 
tempfile-3.php 
... 
tempfile-255.php
```

What I need to do is to redirect the files respectively to:

```
temp-file-1.php 
temp-file-2.php 
temp-file-3.php 
... 
temp-file-255.php
```

I know how to rewrite it one by one, but that is not as solution. 
Can you help to rewrite these type of links in wildcard rule/cond?
Thanks a lot in Advance.

Comment: @anubhava - Could you be so kind to take a look at this

Comment: Use a regex. Lots of articles on this. Ie http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/htaccess-redirect-rewrite-rules.html

Comment: yes truth, there is a lot of artice about this topic, still having problem to solve it

Comment: Rewrite or redirect?

Comment: I don't know mod-rewrite, but I can give you the regular expression in sed. Obviously, either "temp" or "file" has to be a constant. I am assuming that the constant is "temp" not "file". This expression ...
sed 's/^temp\(.*-\)\(.*\).php/temp-\1\2/'
... will do what you want.
$ cat links.txt
tempfile-1.php
tempfile-2.php
tempfile-3.php
tempfile-255.php
$ cat links.txt | sed 's/^temp\(.*-\)\(.*\).php/temp-\1\2/'
temp-file-1
temp-file-2
temp-file-3
temp-file-255

Comment: I'm sorry I made a typo. It should be:
$ cat links.txt | sed 's/^temp\(.*-\)\(.*.php\)/temp-\1\2/'
temp-file-1.php
temp-file-2.php
temp-file-3.php
temp-file-255.php
The regular expression says: replace a pattern with "temp" at the beginning of the line followed by any number of characters followed by one dash, and save these characters and the dash in numbered save 1, put everything else into number save 2, then replace this by numbered save one, followed by a dash, followed by numbered save 2.

Comment: This is even simpler and more general:
$ cat links.txt | sed 's/^temp\\(.*-\\)\\(.*\\)/temp-\1\2/'
temp-file-1.php
temp-file-2.php
temp-file-3.php
temp-file-255.php
The regular expression says: replace a pattern with "temp" at the beginning of the line followed by any number of characters followed by one dash, and save these characters and the dash in numbered save 1, put everything else into numbered save 2, then replace this by numbered save one, followed by one dash, followed by numbered save 2.

Comment: There are certain characters that didn't show up correctly in some of my comments, in particular backslashes.

Comment: Common .htaccess Redirects https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming keyword `file` is present in all the links, you can use this single generic redirect rule in your site root .htaccess to redirect all links:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(temp)(file-.+\.php)$ /$1-$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

- `(temp.+)` is 1st group that matches starting `temp`
- `file-\d+\.php` is 2nd captured group that starts with `file` and ends with `.php`

Comment: hello. sorry for late response. it is important for me for "temp" to be specified, as there are similar file groups. And i need to address this "temp" group only. I also didnt specify that after "file-" are not numbers only but also letters so d+ applies only to numbers. I come up with something like this but doesnt seem to work.  ......     RewriteRule (/^temp/)(file-\[a-zA-Z0-9]\.php)$ /$1-$2 [L,NC,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, when working correctly you can change `R=302` to `R=301`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)(file-\d+).php$ $1-file-$2.php [R=302,L]
```